# Values (or positions) of array row elements within a specified number of positions from target value

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I have the need to collect values from the rows of rectangular arrays of arbitrary precision integers, given a target element value and allowed "distance" (positions +/- within the row from found targets).

E.g., given a target array of

```
ar={{6, 10, 6, 5, 7}, {10, 2, 2, 0, 7}, {0, 6, 3, 7, 5}, {2, 8, 6, 9, 1}, {8, 8, 5, 0, 8}}
```

and a target value of `5`, with an allowed "distance" of `2`, the result should be

```
{10, 6, 5, 7, 3, 7, 5, 8, 8, 5, 0, 8}
```

Result must be order-preserving, i.e., as if the array were "read" left to right, top to bottom.

I'm using this:

```
nearEles[array_, ele_, dist_, posOnly_: False] := 
  With[{r = Range[-dist, dist], d = Dimensions[array][[2]]},
   If[posOnly, #, Extract[array, #]] &[SparseArray[
      Map[IntegerDigits[BitOr @@ (BitShiftLeft[FromDigits[#, 2], r]), 2, d] &,
           SparseArray[BitXor[1, Unitize[array- ele]]]]]["NonzeroPositions"]]];
```

so in the above example, called as `nearEles[ar,5,2]` gets me what I need.

On actual data (typically 1K X 1K to 4K X 2K array size), performs pretty well.

Any ideas for a more efficient (and perhaps less ungainly) method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurred to me that this problem can be recast as an image processing one.  I think this approach is different enough to warrant its own answer.  I like the style much better.

```
f3[array_List, ele_, dist_] :=
  Image[array] ~Binarize~ {ele, ele} ~MaxFilter~ {0, dist} //
    Join @@ Pick[array, ImageData @ #, 1] &

f3[ar, 5, 2]
```

> ```
> {10, 6, 5, 7, 3, 7, 5, 8, 8, 5, 0, 8}
> ```

For best performance in version 7, before `Pick` was optimized, use `"NonzeroPositions"`:

```
f3v7[array_List, ele_, dist_] :=
  Image[array] ~Binarize~ {ele, ele} ~MaxFilter~ {0, dist} //
    array ~Extract~ SparseArray[ImageData @ #]["NonzeroPositions"] &
```

This is faster than my `f2` function from the other answer, especially with large *distance* values:

```
big = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {5000, 5000}];

(r2 = f2[big, 3, 8]) // Timing // First
(r3 = f3v7[big, 3, 8]) // Timing // First

r2 == r3
```

> ```
> 1.232
>
> 0.562
>
> True
> ```

Comment: Ah, *super* clever! f3v7 wins in my tests (interesting that v7 needs `Normal` in your other solution, btw). +1 and accept, don't see this being bettered. Thanks as always!

Comment: @rasher You're welcome.  So `f3v7` is faster than `f3` even in version 9?  Perhaps that is become of the need for `Join` in `f3`.

Comment: Yep, not hugely, but consistently. Even stranger, I'd tried  methods using both `MaxFilter` and `Dilation` on straight arrays. `Dilation` is *vastly* faster when array is converted to image, operated, and converted back even though results are the same. Strange, must be some magic-sauce like it "knowing" about `Unitize` and optimizing. I fell a bit DOH giving up on it and assuming conversion would make it slower...

Comment: @rasher For some reason I forget about `MaxFilter`.  I just tried it and it's as fast as `Dilation` on an `Image`.  I think I'll update my answer to use it since it's somewhat cleaner.  As to why the filters are faster on `Image` I'll do some investigating, but I know that the `Image` format has changed since v7.  (I believe it is now atomic, i.e. `AtomQ` yields true?)

Comment: @rasher I updated my answer, including a better example of the performance advantage of this method over `f2`.

Comment: Yes, `AtomQ` yields true - *very* interesting! This prompts me to investigate its use elsewhere - some quick tests on `Dilation` show a nearly 100:1 advantage on a 500x500 array with a +/-2 window converting to image first. Using `MaxFilter` on your code is a wash speed wise in the tests I just did, but hey, saves some typing, Mr. Terse ;-}

Comment: Oops - happened to glance a timings today, had order reversed, so above comment re: SA vs Pick is backward - it is Pick (at least on v9) that had the consistent advantage. Sorry about misleading boo-boo...

Comment: @rasher well nuts :-p -- okay, time to restore that method.

Answer (score 2):

I got an error running your code in version 7 and I had to use `FromDigits[Normal@#, 2]` to fix it.  Therefore I don't know if my comparative timings are meaningful but here is what I came up with:

```
f2[array_, ele_, dist_] :=
  SparseArray[Unitize[array - ele], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"] //
    Outer[Plus, Range[-dist, dist], #, 1] & //
      Clip[Join ~MapThread~ #, {1, Length @ First @ array}] & //
        Join @@ MapThread[Part, {array, Union /@ #}] &
```

This runs twice as fast as your (modified) code on my machine:

```
big = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {3500, 3500}];

(r1 = nearEles[big, 7, 2]) // Timing // First
(r2 = f2[big, 7, 2])       // Timing // First

r1 == r2
```

> ```
> 0.483
>
> 0.234
>
> True
> ```